# run Cython in Jupyter cdef

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, jupyter-notebook

I am looking for incorporate some cython to speed my code.
I get a issue with running cython code in Jupyter.

cell 1:

```
%%cython
cdef fuc():
    cdef int a = 0
    for i in range(10):
        a += i
        print(a)
```

cell 2:

```
fuc()
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-10789e9d47b8> in <module>()
----> 1 fuc()

NameError: name 'fuc' is not defined
```

but if i do this, it works fine.

```
%%cython
def fuc():
    cdef int a = 0
    for i in range(10):
        a += i
        print(a)
```

Looks like cdef is using differently in Jupyter, how could I use cdef in Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`cdef` functions can only be called from Cython, not Python](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#python-functions-vs-c-functions). The documentation says

> Within a Cython module, Python functions and C functions can call each other freely, but only Python functions can be called from outside the module by interpreted Python code.

(having already stated that "C functions" are defined by `cdef` and "Python functions" by `def`.)

Use a `def` function in Cython instead. It's still compiled by Cython. You can still `cdef` types within your `def` function.

Answer (score 2):

> how could I use cdef in Jupyter notebook?

Try to change **cdef** into **cpdef**.