# How to declare global variables with Cython in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, global-variables, jupyter-notebook, cython

I have a few variables that should be accessible globally in the program. Since they are used so often I'm thinking of giving them a type which from my understanding would speed things up.

I'm not able to do this. In one block in the Jupyter Notebook I have this:

```
%%cython
cdef int magic_number = 42
```

In the next block I get the following error:

```
print(magic_number)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-a40fcb730ac3> in <module>()
----> 1 print(magic_number)

NameError: name 'magic_number' is not defined
```

`cpdef` also doesn't work. How can I get global variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty similar problem to the question "[run Cython in Jupyter cdef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725273/run-cython-in-jupyter-cdef)" - `cdef` objects aren't accessible from Python.

If you want the variable to be accessible from Python then just declare it in the normal Python way

```
magic_number = 42
```

Be aware that you can't type these variables. I don't think there would be any way to use the Python C API to create a "module property" to access C variables, and so Cython is unable to do this. If it's important that these variables are typed in Cython then you will have to create accessor functions to interact with them from Python:

```
%%cython
cdef int magic_number = 42
def get_magic_number():
    global magic_number # not strictly necessary, but clearer
    return magic_number
def set_magic_number(int value):
    global magic_number # necessary
    magic_number = value
```

---

(Note that `cpdef` is only for functions and doesn't make sense for a variable definition.)

Comment: I tried to split the last block you gave as example, the first two lines made the first block and the rest (with %%cython added to the first line) made the second block. It doesn't work. It only works if everything is in one block (like you did). Why?

Comment: Because anything `cdef`ed (except a `cdef class`) can _only_ be accessed through Cython. The two functions are compiled with Cython (hence in the Cython block) but callable from Python. Their purpose is to give a way of accessing the variable from Python